# Is there a way to concatenate across rows and columns in QuickBase?

Tags: quickbase

[image]

As it stands, I have a student table (where each student has a unique row) and an exam table (where each student's exam attempt has a row; the student table is one to many to the exam table).

I want to see if it's possible to add a column to the students table that captures all of the student's exam attempts for a particular exam (as you see below). I was thinking this might require a for loop, but I'm not sure how to do that in QuickBase.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Combined Text Summary field on the Students table for each Exam type.
[image]

Comment: Wow, this did what I needed perfectly! Thank you so much.